# Issue saving PFobjects into an array when using pickerView

Tags: swift, pfquery

i'm relatively new to Swift. I've encountered an issue when using PFQuery in pickerView.

I'm trying to implement a 2 component pickerView as demonstrated below:

Component 0:     Component 1

"A":              "Altivo", "Altrez"

"B": "Beverly", "Bijou"

Choosing "A" from Component 0 will show "Altivo", "Altrez" in Component 1

The values from Component 1 are queried from Parse by using the value from Component 0

Here's my code:

```
var condoNameList: [String] = [String]()
var condoPicker = UIPickerView()
var condoAlphabet: [String] = [String]()
private let prefixComponent = 0
private let condoNameComponent = 1


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    condoAlphabet = ["A", "B"]
 }

 //Start: For condoName picker
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if component == prefixComponent{
        return condoAlphabet.count
    }else {
        return self.condoNameList.count

    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if component == prefixComponent {
        condoNameList.removeAll()
        let query = PFQuery(className: "condodirectory")
        let selectedalphabet: String = condoAlphabet[row] as String!

        query.whereKey("condoName", hasPrefix: selectedalphabet)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?)->Void in

            if error == nil{
                for object in objects!{
                    //print(object)
                    let condoName:String = object["condoName"] as! String
                    self.condoNameList.append(condoName)
                }
            }
            //print("condo Name List is \(self.condoNameList)") //Position 1
        }
        print("condo Name List is \(self.condoNameList)") //Position 2
        condoPicker.reloadComponent(condoNameComponent)
        condoPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: condoNameComponent, animated: true)
    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if component == prefixComponent{
        return condoAlphabet[row]
    }else {
        return self.condoNameList[row]
    }
}
```

The issue is at Position 1, the print function is able to print out the condoNameList but at Position 2 it prints an empty array. As a result, the list for Component 1 is not showing up in the PickerView.

Anyone knows why?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: your print position 2 is outside the block. In this case, the print happen before the query. Everything inside de block happens after the query

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem from another thread by using the didset{} method.

```
var condoNameList: [String] = [] {
        didSet {
            self.condoNameListTemp = condoNameList
            condoName.inputView = condoPicker
            condoPicker.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }
```